# Javascript Cookies - adding multiple cookies instead of updating one

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to add a popup pause in one day using JS cookies. Here is teh code:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("expirator") >= 0) {

    // do not show popup

}
else{

    var d = new Date();
    var start_date = d.toUTCString();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));

    var expireDate = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "expirator=1;" + expireDate + "; domain=a5w.org; path=/";

    // show popup
}
```

for a strange reason this scipt adds multiple new cookies with the same name ("expirator") instead of updating one. why is that so?

screenshot from FF cookies:

http://a5w.org/up/uploads/mike/2015-10-10/1444519970_cookies.png

Comment: There's a missing space in `expirator=1;` would that cause an issue?

Comment: nope, that shuldn't be a problem but I have just tried with no result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't update cookies; you need to overwrite them.

Two cookies may have the same name if they were set for different domains or paths.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242446/280842

**EDIT**

There seems to be a bug in Firefox that displays multiple cookies in Firefox cookie manager. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504086

Comment: isn't that what he is doing?

Comment: emm.. isn't it the same? to update - simply to overwrte?

Comment: How do you know that multiple cookies are being added? You can look at the resources tab on the chrome developer tools

Comment: paths are the same...domains are the same... the only difference is the expiration date.

Comment: @Rossitten my guess is this is a bug in Firefox, what's the result on chrome?

Comment: @Filype - now that's really weird. NO cookies in Chrome are set.
and your example seems to be working fine...hmm...................

Comment: Be damned FF! 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504086
@Filype  - you were right in your guess! add that as your answer, pelase so I can accept that.

Comment: @Rossitten updated the answer. Interesting discovery.